# Nested JSON parse with facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

Thanks for reading!

I am trying to develop an android app, but I was stuck on how to fetch user's "likes". All I need are just the values for each "name" key. Here, those would be "Jay Chou", "Eason Chan" and "Facebook Developers". Below is the JSON text

```
{
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "111735208843636", 
      "name": "Chinese"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "106059522759137", 
      "name": "English"
    }
  ], 
  "id": "100005065353669", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "Musician/band", 
        "name": "Jay Chou", 
        "id": "109155665769390", 
        "created_time": "2013-06-11T18:54:44+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "category": "Musician/band", 
        "name": "Eason Chan", 
        "id": "105468519487919", 
        "created_time": "2013-06-05T20:33:26+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "category": "Product/service", 
        "name": "Facebook Developers", 
        "id": "19292868552", 
        "created_time": "2013-05-31T01:35:17+0000"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100005065353669/likes?    limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=19292868552"
    }
  }
}
```

This piece of code is for fetching user's "language", and it works perfectly fine for me.

```
 JSONArray languages = (JSONArray)user.getProperty("languages");
 if (languages.length() > 0) {
   ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String> ();

   for (int i=0; i < languages.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject language = languages.optJSONObject(i);
       languageNames.add(language.optString("name"));
   }
   userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n", languageNames.toString()));
 }
```

`user` comes from the function parameter `private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user)` and `userinfo` comes from `StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");`

Can anyone help me? Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exaclty correct as i cant test it right now, but it should work in this way. dont forget to check if there is a property called "likes" and if there is an array called "data" in the json representation before using it to prevent NullPointers though.

```
List<String> likes = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject jsonLikes = (JSONObject) user.getProperty("likes");
JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) likes.getProperty("data");

for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    likes.add(jsonData.optString("name");
}
```

the list likes then contains all "name" attributes of the likes.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have used almost exact same code as you provided, it throws NullPointer error on getProperty("data") line. I cannot figure out how it would happen. I mean there should be a JSON array named "data".

Comment: which json library are you using?